# Unable to convert expression type predicate to return type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda

I am having a repository with a generic method

```
 public IQueryable<TEntity> Populate<TEntity1>(Func<TEntity, TEntity1> predicate)
    {
        return (IQueryable<TEntity>)_objectSet.Select(predicate);
    }
```

and a class which calls this method

```
 public IDictionary<int,string> Populatelist()
    {
        var dic =_repository.Populate<DTO.Category>(category => new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }).ToList();

        return dic.ToDictionary(c => c.CategoryID, c => c.CategoryName);

    }
```

But i dont know why it is displaying

> Unable to convert expression type predicate: category => new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName } to return type DTO.Category

any guess ?

Comment: well if i am replacing Func<TEntity, TEntity1> with Func<TEntity, object> its not showing any compilation error but during run its displaying cannot convert object to DTO.Category type....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found the solution...The signature should be

```
List<TResult> Populate<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> predicate);
```

The Implementation in the Repository Class

```
public List<TResult> Populate<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> source)
{
        return _objectSet.Select(source).ToList();
}
```

Now use this from the Business Logic For Eg-

```
    public IDictionary<int,string> Populatelist( )
    {

        var expectedResult =_repository.Populate(category => new {category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName}).ToList();

        return expectedResult.ToDictionary(c => c.CategoryID, c => c.CategoryName);

    }
```

The problem was as the return type was anonymous so that was creating the problem when passing the value, now the return type is Tresult of list type so no casting error..

Answer (score 1):

```
    public IQueryable<TEntity1> Populate<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, TEntity1> predicate)
    {
        return (IQueryable<TEntity1>)_objectSet.Select(predicate);
    }

    public IDictionary<int, string> Populatelist()
    {
        var dic = _repository.Populate<DTO.Category>(category => new DTO.Category() { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }).ToList();

        return dic.ToDictionary(c => c.CategoryID, c => c.CategoryName);

    }
```

I hope this will help. in Lambdaexpression use new DTO.Category() instead of anonymous type.

Comment: well actually it has no relation with i create a anonymous or DTO.Category type, it is just that it is unable to recognize the whole expression....

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
_repository.Populate(category => ...
```

instead of

```
_repository.Populate<DTO.Category>(category => ...
```

Also the return type of `Popualte` should probably be `IQueryable<TEntity1>` and the cast should be removed.

---

**Explanation**

The follwoing method

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Populate<TEntity1>(Func<TEntity, TEntity1> predicate)
```

excepts a `Func<TEntity, TEntity1>` as argument.

So if you call this method with `DTO.Category` as `TEntity1`, it expects `predicate` to be a `Func<TEntity, DTO.Category>`.

So you call `.Populate<DTO.Category>`, but your argument is not a `Func<TEntity, DTO.Category>`, it's `category => new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }`, an expression that returns a new anonymous type.

Hence the error message is quite clear in saying it can't convert your expression, since it expects a function that returns a `DTO.Category`.

---

**Conclusion**

I guess `DTO.Category` is just `TEntity` of your `_repository`.

So you just want to omit the type paramter.

```
var dic =_repository.Populate(category => new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }).ToList();
```

So the type parameter of `Populate<TEntity1>` will be infered by the compiler: it will be your anomynous type you create with your expression.

Comment: so like as Func<TEntity, TEntity1> states that Tentity would be the supply type and Tentity1 would be the output type omitting the <DTO.Category> will make Tentity1 as a unknown type, so what should be the output type in Func<TEntity, ??????>...


I took Func<TEntity, object > but it did'nt work out, Any guess ??

Comment: @Ankit To get to a solution: what do you `Populate` expect to do?

Comment: i have created a generic Function Populate which will be interacting with the EFM model and performing the select operation from the model based on the expression supplied on to the predicate parameter rather than performing select * operation then again filtering the related values. And in this case i just want the ID and Categoryname columns from the Category entity via this generic method Populate

Comment: @Ankit In this case, the method should return `IQueryable<TEntity1>` instead of `IQueryable<TEntity>`, since you want to return the type your expression evaluates to, not the original type (that would be `SELECT *`). And also the cast `(IQueryable<TEntity>)` is unnecessary. It won't work anyway. It should just read `return _objectSet.Select(predicate);`

Comment: well i tried up everything but in any context the **new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }** parameter is being recognized as Anonymous type and conversion of this Anonymous type to DTO.Category type is not happening, i tried with Ienumerable, Iqueryable , with and without casting, the main issue is how to pass **new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }** to the Populate method...as logically this should be the signature **Func<TEntity, TEntity>** but it is unable to cast the expression to DTO.CAtegory type....Damn this is pissing me off :X

Comment: @Ankit You just can't cast your anonymous type to DTO.Category. Why do you want to do this? It's not necessary at all.

Comment: if the casting can't be done then how to pass **new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }** this to the generic method **public IEnumerable<TEntity> Populate(Func<TEntity, TEntity> predicate)

        {
            return _objectSet.Select(predicate);
        } **

Comment: The return type has to be `IEnumerable<TEntity1>`, otherwise it would not make sense. Maybe rename `TEntity` to `TSource` and `TEntity1` to `TResult` to make it clearer.

Comment: well i guess der seems to be some problem with the clause Select i guess it will not be working out this way....Looks need to do more brainstorming on this, Thnx anyway for the effort :)

Answer (score -2):

The return type of your method is IQueryable, but instead your method is returning an anonymous type 

    new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }

which is not convertible to TEntity.

also, i think it safer to use 
    return _objectSet.Select(predicate).AsQueryable();

btw, predicate is not a good name for your parameter since predicate means a lambda that distinguishes between items by returning a bool that marks if the item passes the test (e.g.  the predicate parameter of the Where extension method)
as

in this helpful?